# How can I connect and upload to this FTP host on the console?

Tags: console, ftp, file-transfer

A vendor has provided these FTP connection params so I can upload some data for them...

**Host:** host.com
**Port:** 46800
**Protocol:** FTP – File Transfer Protocol
**Encryption:** Require implicit FTP over TLS
**Logon Type:** Normal
**User:** [ username ]
**Password:** [ password ]

It isn't working for me...

```
$ ftp -p host.com 46800
Connected to host.com
421 Service not available, user interrupt. Connection closed.
ftp>
```

I suspect the "Require implicit FTP over TLS" param might be the issue? (Maybe?)

TLS isn't mentioned in the FTP man page.

What would be a command that would allow me to connect and upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ftp` program is for the insecure `ftp` protocol.  Your vendor has specified that you use Implicit FTP over TLS which is a way to encrypt the connection and keep your credentials and data private over the Internet.

Fortunately, there is a program called `lftp` which understands this protocol.

```
lftp
open -u [username] ftps://host.com:46800
Password: [enter your password]
ls
[your remote files should be listed]
```

`lftp` supports many protocols.  This [webpage](http://linux.overshoot.tv/wiki/networking/lftp#A_multitude_of_protocols) lists them in an easy to read table.